# image control - dynamic load image from the resource file

Tags: wpf

I create in the code some image control and i want to set on this image control some of the picture that i saved ( load those pictures before creating the image control )

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify your image in your Resource like this

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="SampleImageSource" UriSource="sample.png" />
```

and assign that to your image control like

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource SampleImageSource}" />
```

or if you are trying to do in code

```
img.Source = (ImageSource) Resources["SampleImageSource"];
```